# how to python3.10.5 execute from javascript fetch

Tags: python

client.js

```
fetch('/a.py', {method:'POST',body:"aa"}).then(res=>res.text()).then(res=>console.log(res))
```

a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("HTTP/2.0 200 OK")
print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
print(sys.path)
```

> ['/var/html', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
> '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
> '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
> '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

$ python a.py

> ['/var/html', '/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python310.zip',
> '/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10',
> '/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
> '/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

I want 3.10.5 to JavaScript Fetch but 3.6

3.6 is not pip install.
pip3.6 install pymongo is BAD.

I tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!python3
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

but 502 error
/var/log/nginx/error.log

> upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response
> header from upstream or ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'pymongo'" while reading response header from upstream

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python3 -V` - if you type that in, what version of python3 do you get? Sounds like you have multiple versions installed and 3.6 is likely higher in precedence in pathing.

Comment: The code you provided never imports `pymongo`. Please include the code that caused the error or remove it before testing

Comment: /usr/bin/env python3 -V Python 3.10.5 and pyenv global 3.10.5

Comment: Since you're using pyenv, you have to make sure that the `PATH` being used by your server process is correct. You set `pyenv global` for yourself (looks like you're running `root` user, maybe in a container), but the server process is probably running under a very different user. You'll need to configure `pyenv` or the right path or python version for whoever that user is.

Comment: Resolved. `ln -s -f /root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10 /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.10  -m pip install boto3`